# How to view updated state in another reducer?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I've 2 reducers A, B residing in packages A and B respectively. I've a store in package A which combines both reducers.

Package A consumes package B. However, package B has a `form` which upon submission must update the components defined in package A. I've defined an action in package B and want reducer A to handle that action.

I am able to get to the case statement for the action but the state in the reducer A doesn't reflect the global state. I thought once the store's state was updated all the reducers states' which make up the store would be updated but that doesn't seem to be the case. Reducer A is maintaining its own state which is a subset of the global store state. How do I make reducer A access the state updates brought by reducer B?

One thought I had was to merge reducer B within A but that would make package B dependent on A. I haven't tried using `redux-form` since we've our own internal components for form elements. Any other thoughts/suggestions?

Update : Adding some code, the action types are constants defined as strings. Upon submission of the form I want `SUBMIT_COURSE_DATA` action to be dispatched and have the state updated in reducer A. Store is essentially using `combineReducers` to combine the reducers A and B.

```
// Reducer B
const bReducer = (state = {
selectedCourse: {
     courseType: ""
 },  
}, action) => {
  const newState = Object.assign({}, state);
switch (action.type) {
    case COURSE_DATA_CHANGE:
          newState.selectedCourse.courseType = action.courseType;
  } 
};

export default bReducer;  

// Action B 
 export function handleCourseDataChange(courseType) {
 return {
    type: COURSE_DATA_CHANGE,
    courseType : courseType
 }
}

 export function submitCourseData() {
  return {
    type: SUBMIT_COURSE_DATA,
  }
}

 //Reducer A

    const formReducers = (state = {
    coursesContext: {
    data: [],
    actions: []
  },  
}, action) => {  
const newState = Object.assign({}, state);  
 case SUBMIT_COURSE_DATA:
      newState.coursesContext.data = [newState.coursesContext.data, Object.assign({},
        {"Course_Type": newState.selectedCourse.courseType})];
    return newState;


     // store.js
        import { reducers as modalManagerReducers } from 'modal';
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import reduceReducers  from 'reduce-reducers';
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';
import { baseReducers } from '../../../packageB/src/components/AddCourseDialog';
import  courseFormReducers from './reducers';
import  formSubmissionReducer from './formReducer';
import { SUBMIT_COURSE_DATA } from '../../../packageB/src/components/actions';

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();

const courseReducer = Object.assign({}, { model: courseFormReducers });

const mainReducer = combineReducers(Object.assign({}, baseReducers, courseReducer, modalManagerReducers ));

const formSubmissionReducer = function(state,action) {
   switch (action.type)
   {
       case SUBMIT_COURSE_DATA:
           return formSubmissionReducer(state.selectedCourse);

       default:
           return state;
   }
};

const rootReducer = reduceReducers(mainReducer, formSubmissionReducer);

const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    compose(applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware)),
);

export  {store, sagaMiddleware};

// formSubmissionReducer is same as reducer A. Just that now reducer A
   doesn't have a case for SUBMIT_COURSE_DATA anymore.

//AddCourseDialog 

// Form Submit handler
 handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.dispatch(submitCourseData());
}

    // How to ensure that formSubmissionReducer in the store gets invoked here?
    const baseReducers = Object.assign({}, { baseReducer: courseBaseReducers });
export { baseReducers };

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AddCourseDialog);
```

**Updated** to include the `AddCourseDialog` container which handles the on change and submit events by dispatching actions.

Comment: first of all without code examples we can't really help you, but in general reducers can't and should not know about other reducer's portion of the store as the whole idea is that each reducer supposed to manage only subset of the store. one solution is to create a middle ware that has access to the whole store and the action being dispatched and dispatch another action with relevant data to a different reducer, another approach is dispatch another action within your action creator. but again, without code examples it's hard to know what are your best choices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [Redux FAQ entry on sharing state between slice reducers](http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/Reducers.html#reducers-share-state):

> Many users later want to try to share data between two reducers, but find that `combineReducers` does not allow them to do so. There are several approaches that can be used:
>
> - If a reducer needs to know data from another slice of state, the state tree shape may need to be reorganized so that a single reducer is handling more of the data.
> - You may need to write some custom functions for handling some of these actions. This may require replacing `combineReducers` with your own top-level reducer function. You can also use a utility such as reduce-reducers to run `combineReducers` to handle most actions, but also run a more specialized reducer for specific actions that cross state slices.
> - Async action creators such as redux-thunk have access to the entire state through `getState()`. An action creator can retrieve additional data from the state and put it in an action, so that each reducer has enough information to update its own state slice.

There's also [many other third-party reducer utilities available](https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links/blob/master/reducers.md), and some of those may be useful.  In particular, you might want to look at [ryo33/combine-section-reducers](https://github.com/ryo33/combine-section-reducers), [convoyinc/combined-reduction](https://github.com/convoyinc/combined-reduction), and [KodersLab/topologically-combine-reducers](https://github.com/KodersLab/topologically-combine-reducers).

**update**

Per your question about why "`r` isn't a reducer", right now you have:

```
const courseReducer = Object.assign({}, { model: courseFormReducers });

const mainReducer = Object.assign({}, baseReducers, courseReducer,        
                                 modalManagerReducers );
```

That's *not* what you need.  You need to pass those slice reducers to `combineReducers` to form the initial "per-slice handling" reducer.  Then, if you do want to use `reduceReducers`, pass both of the "top-level state" reducers in.  Here's an example:

```
const combinedReducer = combineReducers({
    model : courseFormReducers,
    anotherSlice : anotherSliceReducer
});

const rootReducer = reduceReducers(combinedReducer, formSubmissionReducer);

const store = createStore(rootReducer);
```

Comment: I was looking at this gist - https://gist.github.com/markerikson/b1a22137527bf8e0ce6928ffb8e46fe7 for using `reduce-reducers`. Can I use it within `store.js`? I mean within `store.js` I create the `rootReducer` before creating the `store`. I am running into `TypeError: r is not a function at createStore(rootReducer)` and am not sure what that means. Any ideas?

Comment: You might want to look at my blog post [Practical Redux, Part 7](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/01/practical-redux-part-7-forms-editing-reducers/) for some examples of using `reduceReducers()`.  Other than that, it sounds like your `rootReducer` variable isn't actually a reducer function.  Can you add your `store.js` file to the original question?

Comment: I'll look at your blog post and have updated the question with the `store.js`. I've introduced a new reducer to handle course submission.

Comment: I made some progress but now I am getting `Cannot read property 'type' of undefined at formSubmissionReducer`. So, it seems like the action type is undefined. How does the dispatcher in package B know that this reducer in store in package A needs to be invoked?

Comment: I've updated the code to reflect the `AddCourseDialog` container which dispatches actions on data change and submit. I'm not yet sure how the store's `formSubmissionReducer` is going to be invoked here.

Comment: It's a bit hard to give specific advice at this point without seeing the rest of your code, preferably all at once. I'd actually encourage you to drop by the Reactiflux chat rooms at https://www.reactiflux.com , and post a link to your repo in the `#need-help` chat channel. There's a good chance someone should be able to answer things there.

Comment: Turns out that I defined `formSubmissionReducer` to have an action when I was only passing it the state. The issue is resolved, thanks for all the help.